# Python Dash APP shows previous page dropdowns on current page after navigation. How to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am working on the Multipage Dash Application. I have drop-downs on each page to filter the reports.
whenever I am navigating from one page to another page then sometimes previous page dropdowns are appearing on current page. Once we refresh complete URL the dropdowns appear appropriately.

Please help if to get rid of this behavior of Dash.

Tried with couple of things, not able to sure these are relevant or not.

app = dash.Dash(**name**, suppress_callback_exceptions=True, use_pages=True)

server = app.server

dash.register_page(**name**, path='/')

Expecting Only current page drop-down will appear on page navigation